# How do I make certain list items lowercase using str.lower() if they appear on another list?

Tags: python, list, filter, lowercase

I've been trying to solve a problem on CodeWars and have hit a roadblock. I know this is not a particularly "pythonic" approach (I'm a beginner).  And I'm sure there are more efficient and advanced ways to do it.  But I'm really just trying to understand why the code below isn't working.  I just want to make string items of a list lower case if they appear on another list of filter words.  (Disregard the code to remove the first item.  That's because the task requires treating the first item differently).

```
def title_case(title, minors=''):
    title = title.title()
    mwds = minors.split()
    lst = title.split(" ", 1)

    exfirst = lst[1].split()
    for wd in exfirst:
        wd.lower()
        if wd in mwds:
            wd.lower()
    return exfirst

print(title_case('a clash of KINGS', 'a an the of'))
print(title_case('THE WIND IN THE WILLOWS', 'The In'))
```

Result:

```
['Clash', 'Of', 'Kings']
['Wind', 'In', 'The', 'Willows']
```

Expected result:

```
['Clash', 'of', 'Kings']
['Wind', 'in', 'the', 'Willows']
```

Comment: Your code is malformatted, please fix the indentation.  `str.lower()` returns a lower case copy of the string, it does not mutate the original one. Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you don't assign the new minor to old minor. To make assigns, you must use index as iterator on exfirst list.

```
for i in range(exfirst):
    wd= exfirst[i].lower()
    if wd in mwds:
        exfirst[i] = wd
```

Answer (score 0):

The lower() method doesn't change characters in place. You should do:

```
wd = wd.lower()
```